# Sierra as NFS/LDAP client: write permissions problems

Tags: macos, permission, nfs

I have set up an NFS/LDAP client under Sierra and I have write permissions problems with the user profile. Some installed applications do not want to launch with the user account such as LibreOffice, Filezilla, Opera... I use `/etc/auto_master` and `/etc/auto_nfs`

The user manages very well to write on his account nfs

Here's what it is:

```
+auto_master # Use directory service
/net -hosts -nobrowse, hidefromromfinder, nosuid
/home auto_home -nobrowse, hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers -fstab
/- - - Static
#/- auto_nfs -nobrowse, nosuid
/- auto_nfs -nobrowse, nosuid


/home1 -fstype=nfs, noowners, rw, resvport, nolockd, hard, bg, intr, nfc 192.31.21.33:/home1
/home2 -fstype=nfs, noowners, rw, resvport, nolockd, hard, bg, intr, nfc 192.31.21.33:/home2
```

Answer (score 1):

I deleted nolockd and it works much better.